# Is believing in the division of Tawheed by Ibn Taymiyah an act of Bid'ah?

Tags: tawheed

While it is useful as an academic and scholastic approach to divide Tawheed into categories for further in depth understanding - are the ones who believe and preach it **as if it was an integral** part of Islam an act of innovation?

There's quite a worrying trend amongst students of knowledge where they put the division of Tawheed in 3 as a necessity - oblivious to the fact that it could be divided more or even shortened if put forth in a new scholastic and academic model.

Comment: to answer questions like these one must define what a bidah is. would grammar (na7o), tafsir, usul al fiqh, be a bidah? everything needs to be defined

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not say so. The issue here isn't the three categories of Tawheed as a teaching model. Ultimately, the three category system is the derived from the Qur'an itself [nothing new added or subtracted] so there is nothing innovated or wrong as far as this **categorization** is concerned.

The only issue here is the **response** of some people who you imply are insistent upon this particular model over others. Perhaps some of them do not know the history/purpose of categorization to begin with, in which case it is just *ignorance* to blame. Or perhaps others of them just cling to it because their scholars categorize it that way, in which case it is *blind fanaticism* to blame.

Those are the real issues (ignorance/fanaticism), but the categorization for learning itself is fine.

Comment: I'm asking whether this ignorance/persistence constitutes religious innovation.

Comment: No. How could it when it isn't adding or taking away from Islam?

Comment: If the division of 3 is being believed as a foundational part of Islam - and not just a mere explanation - this is potentially trespassing in innovation. That is my question.

Comment: It seems to me like you've already made your mind up on the answer before you even asked. -- It is foundational in the sense that these categories do exist. If someone's Ijtihad is that it is 3 or someone Ijtihad is that it is 4 [and they stick to it] then that is their right to believe so. It is not "innovation". Are you saying these people make Takfir of anyone who doesn't believe in 3 categories?

Comment: I've heard that the division is a cause of contention, which is why I'm looking for scholarly opinions from either side. And yes, it seems that some are either throwing takfir or labeling others as misguided if they follow another model or disagree with parts of it.

Comment: @HouseoftheGoldenAxe does my answer make sense or do i have to explain more?